# How to send Message from Node JS to C++ code

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I am running C++ program using Node js and the C++ program will start with one process ID in Linux. Now I would like to send a message from Node JS to the C++ program using the process Id which was started.

Below is the code sample for calling C++ from Node JS

```
childout = cp.spawn('/home/build/eth/eth',['-i'], function(error, stdout, stderr){
   console.log("stdout :: " +stdout);
   console.log("stderror :: " +stderr);
   console.log("error :: " +error);
});
```

The above code is starting C++ and having process Id. Now I need to send a message using this process ID.

Can any one please guide me how to achieve this task?

Comment: You could use the pid (on both ends) for naming a named pipe or a unix domain socket. You could also just use the child processes stdin/stdout(/stderr) for talking with it. Lots of possibilities... Read up on [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) for ideas.

Comment: Only thing you can do with just PID alone is send UNIX signals, but then you can't really include a message with it, beyond having a few different signals (say, HUP, USR1, USR2) to mean different things.

Comment: why don't you just spawn and then use `spawn.stdin.write` directly?